# Where can I learn more about parsing text in Java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-parsing

I'm in a Data Structures class (in Java) this semester, but we're doing a lot of parsing on text files to populate the structures we design.  The focus is on the structures themselves, not on parsing algorithms.  I feel sort of weak in the area and was wondering if anyone could point me to a book or site on the subject.  Design patterns, libraries, styles, etc.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For parsing basic text files in Java, I would start by examining the Scanner class:

- [Java Scanner Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)
- [Java Scanner API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

For any Text parsing, a basic knowledge of Regex is a good thing to have:

- [Java Regex Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/)

If Scanner isn't doing the job, you can always parse through a text file line-by-line with a BufferedReader backed by a FileReader.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path/to/file.txt"));
for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
{
    //process your line here
}
```

Scanner may again be useful here, and you could also look into String.split(), or the java Pattern API.

- [Java String.split() API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Java Pattern API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Files can be in many formats however. For advice on the best way to parse a file of a file in a given well-defined format, google will be your friend. Or you can always post a more specific quesiton here with the format that is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The book "Design Patterns" describes the structure of a recursive-descent parser.

The [javacc](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) compiler-compiler can be used to generate parsers in Java.

Comment: This is great for more advanced parsing such as defining a simple grammar.  We used it in my firm to define a SQL-like domain-specific query language.

Comment: @Adamski: Indeed, I've used javacc several times.  As an old yacc(1) user, I was impressed by its simplicity and power.

Answer (score 1):

You can do basic text parsing with the StringTokenizer class, the String.split() methods, and the Pattern and Matcher classes for regular expressions.